# How to change the style of Upload Document Dialog box?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

I am building a SharePoint 2010 intranet. I want to get rid of the master page heading in the popup dialog box (Upload document and display other things). How can I get rid off the master page heading for this dialog alone.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you have changed the master page and some elements like logo or navigation or some such now appear in the modal dialogs. To hide these elements in the dialogs, you can apply the class "s4-notdlg" to each of the unwanted elements.

```
<div class="s4-notdlg">
```

Comment: In v4.master there are several s4-notdlg. I am not sure how I can hide the header inside a popupwindow (upload document dialog). As soon as you click the "add new document" link this upload document dialog appears. Do you know the css class names for the dialog popup?

Comment: I hope you made a copy of v4.master. You can use IE's developer tools to identify the CSS class of screen elements. What exactly in the add document dialog do you want to hide? Things YOU have added or things that are out of the box?