# How to hide the header of Upload Document Dialog?

Tags: 2010, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to get rid of the master page header that appears on the Upload Document popup. How can I accomplish that? Is there any specific css classes that I can use?

When I view the page source of the dialog, it has the master page code on it for displaying this header. How can I hide this header in the dialog alone and not in the main sharepoint page?

Comment: You've already opened a question for that here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58802/how-to-change-the-style-of-upload-document-dialog-box/58821#58821 Why don't you continue the dialog in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

```
.ms-dialog .s4-titletable
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

So you can stop any style from the master page using .ms-dialog with master page css clas

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `'s4-notdlg'` to your HTML element to prevent the element from displaying in your dialogs. It's as simple as that. :-)

Here's a nice [article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-pop-up-dialogs/)  on SharePoint dialogs which covers this as well.

Comment: No that is not I am looking for. That is for manually defined dialogs. But this upload document dialog is predefined. I need to know the css class names to do anything.

Comment: Can you please a screenshot of what you are referring to? The dialogs still use the current site and custom masterpage settings. Simply add the "S4-notdlg" to the correct elements of the site and custom masterpage. It works, I use this to prevent all sorts of options appearing in my dialogs.

Comment: I think he is asking about the Sharepoint builtin Modal and hiding it's header. Not sure why you would do that, but this should suffice:
.ms-dlgTitle
{
 display:none !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

I think he is asking about the Sharepoint builtin Modal and hiding it's header. Not sure why you would do that, but this should suffice:

```
.ms-dlgTitle 
{ 
  display:none !important; 
}
```

Stick this somewhere in your CSS and you're good to go.

Comment: it didn't work. It actually hides the Dialog title and the maximize and close buttons. I need to hide the header below it.

Comment: @G-Man, just upload a screenshot and specify what you are talking about. You're not being clear at all as to what you expect, how can anyone help out when your being so ambiguous?